# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'text' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'text' of undefined" on running the following

```
var years= new Array(113);
for(i=0;i<113;i++){
years[i]["text"]=i+1900;
years[i]["value"]=i+1900;
}
```

Basically, I want something like this to be generated with a loop

```
var years= [
        { text: "1990", value: 1990, },
        { text: "1991", value: 1991, }, //till 2012
];
```

Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want literal notation:

```
var years= new Array(113);
for(i=0;i<113;i++){
    years[i] = {text: String(i + 1900), value: i + 1900};
}
```

The reason you were getting the error is that you never assigned anything to `years[i]`, but you were trying to *use* it in the expression `years[i]["text"]` (which means "get the property with the name from `i` from the `years` object, and then get the property `"text"` from that).

Note that there's no benefit in attempting to pre-allocate room for a standard array in JavaScript, because JavaScript standard arrays [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html). So perhaps:

```
var years= [];
for(i=0;i<113;i++){
    years[i] = {text: String(i + 1900), value: i + 1900};
}
```

Similarly, you could just loop from `1900` (inclusive) to `2013` (exclusive) rather than doing all of that addition in the loop:

```
var years= [];
for(i=1900;i<2013;i++){
    years.push({text: String(i), value: i});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

years[i] is not set to anything (`years[i] == undefined`), so you can't access text on it.  Try it with the following:

```
var years = new Array(113);
for(i=0; i < 113; i++) {
    years[i] = {"text": i+1900, "value": i+1900};
}
```

or

```
var years = new Array();
for(i=0; i < 113; i++) {
    years.push({"text": i+1900, "value": i+1900});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has already been answered but I would suggest using the array literal notation instead of the explicit constructor call.

```
var years = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 133; ++i)
{
    years[i] = {
        text: (i + 1900).toString(),
        value: i + 1900
    };
}
```